# Is it possible to turn on GZIP compression in Phussion Passenger for Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, nginx, gzip, passenger

I'm currently a customer of a little hosting company and I run my Node app there. They have a good user friendly control panel, where you can set up your apps. When you add a new Node app, its automatically set up with Phussion Passenger for Node. Which is good, Passenger takes care of serving static files etc.

Although the service seems not to be yet well tested and polished. The Passenger doesn't GZIP static files, which is very important. Is it possible to turn on GZIP compression in Phussion Passenger for Node.js? Would it be hard? How should it be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it's possible. Passenger integrates with Nginx, and so gzip compression is just done through the Nginx configuration file. Whether you can enable it, depends on whether your hosting provider allows you to modify the Nginx configuration file, or whether they can turn it on for you. If you can modify the Nginx configuration file, just set `gzip on`.

Comment: I finally got an email from my provider. They are working on it, thank you for the answer.